# Unable to jump from one place another properly in excel file using C

Tags: c, excel, csv

I am writing a code in C to write data in `.csv` file. In this code I am just writing `A` in first column for five time then trying to write `B` from beginning of next column. Here is my code:-

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Filename.csv", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
    printf("Couldn't open file\n");
    return 0;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
    fprintf(fp, "A\n");    
    }

    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
    fprintf(fp, ",B\n");    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My output expectation is like this:-

```
A B
A B
A B
A B
A B
```

But I am getting output like this:-

```
A
A
A
A
A
  B
  B
  B
  B
  B
```

My idea is to learn to jump any `column-row` to any `column-row` is `.csv` file.
So, please help me to learn how to jump anywhere in the file.

Comment: You can't do that. Files are written sequentially, character-by-character, line-by-line.

Comment: This is not your real output, the `,` is missing. Show us the actual thing please.

Comment: Sourav:- I have copy and paste the program from my question for precaution, I am again getting the same output as I mentioned, Although I
 have include a space between 'A' and 'B' just to make my question easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse line and join parsed part and a new part and write to file again. I think its not the best way but it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char * line = NULL;

    /* Write first part "A" */
    fp = fopen("Filename.csv", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Write and done */
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) fprintf(fp, "A\n");    
    fclose(fp);


    /* Open templorary file */
    fp = fopen("file.tmp", "a");
    if (fp != NULL) 
    {
        /* Open exiting file */
        fp2 = fopen("Filename.csv", "r");
        if(fp2 != NULL)
        {
            /* Read from exing file */
            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp2)) != -1) 
            {
                /* Remove new line character */
                sscanf(line, "%512[^\n]\n", line);

                /* Join and write to file */
                sprintf(line, "%s B", line);
                fprintf(fp, "%s\n", line);
            }

            /* Clean up memory */
            fclose(fp2);
            if (line) free(line);
        }

        /* End up */
        fclose(fp);
        remove("Filename.csv");
        rename("file.tmp", "Filename.csv");
    }

    return 0;
}
```